# Survey on functional equations and inequalities

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, soft-question, functional-equations

Where can I find a comprehensive survey monograph on functional equations and inequalities from sketch to current research trends with some focus on applications (both *inside* and *outside* mathematics)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Functional Equations and Inequalities with Applications](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=SdZoCM2OeuIC) is a book from 2009 about these topics:

> Functional Equations and Inequalities with Applications presents a comprehensive, nearly encyclopedic, study of the classical topic of functional equations. Nowadays, the field of functional equations is an ever-growing branch of mathematics with far-reaching applications; it is increasingly used to investigate problems in mathematical analysis, combinatorics, biology, information theory, statistics, physics, the behavioral sciences, and engineering. This self-contained monograph explores all aspects of functional equations and their applications to related topics, such as differential equations, integral equations, the Laplace transformation, the calculus of finite differences, and many other basic tools in analysis. Each chapter examines a particular family of equations and gives an in-depth study of its applications as well as examples and exercises to support the material. The book is intended as a reference tool for any student, professional (researcher), or mathematician studying in a field where functional equations can be applied. It can also be used as a primary text in a classroom setting or for self-study. Finally, it could be an inspiring entrée into an active area of mathematical exploration for engineers and other scientists who would benefit from this careful, rigorous exposition.

There also two handbooks from Springer from 2014 with recent developments on stability and functional inequalities, namely [Handbook of Functional Equations: Stability Theory](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/dynamical+systems/book/978-1-4939-1285-8) and [Handbook of Functional Equations: Functional Inequalities](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/dynamical+systems/book/978-1-4939-1245-2)